# Cannot overload class operator * to multiply another of the same class

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a quaternion, so I want to be able to chain multiplications such as `a * b * c`. I've already overloaded the `__mul__` operator, but I get an error which running: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Quat' and 'Quat'`.

On the other hand, if I make a `mult()` method, it works.

```
import math
from .vec3 import Vec3

class Quat:
    @classmethod
    def from_axis_angle(cls, _axis=Vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0), _angle=0.0):
        w = math.cos(_angle * 0.5)
        x = _axis.x * math.sin(_angle * 0.5)
        y = _axis.y * math.sin(_angle * 0.5)
        z = _axis.z * math.sin(_angle * 0.5)
        return cls(w, x, y, z)

    def __init__(self, _w, _x, _y, _z):
        self.w = _w
        self.x = _x
        self.y = _y
        self.z = _z

    def mult(self, _rhs):
        lhs_vec = Vec3(self.x, self.y, self.z)
        rhs_vec = Vec3(_rhs.x, _rhs.y, _rhs.z)
        w = self.w * _rhs.w - lhs_vec.dot(rhs_vec)
        xyz = self.w * rhs_vec + _rhs.w * lhs_vec + lhs_vec.cross(rhs_vec)
        return Quat(w, xyz.x, xyz.y, xyz.z)

    def ___mul__(self, _rhs):
        lhs_vec = Vec3(self.x, self.y, self.z)
        rhs_vec = Vec3(_rhs.x, _rhs.y, _rhs.z)
        w = self.w * _rhs.w - lhs_vec.dot(rhs_vec)
        xyz = self.w * rhs_vec + _rhs.w * lhs_vec + lhs_vec.cross(rhs_vec)
        return Quat(w, xyz.x, xyz.y, xyz.z)
    
    def __rmul__(self, _rhs):
        return _rhs.__mul__(self)

    def to_axis_angle(self):
        xyz = Vec3(self.x, self.y, self.z)
        if xyz.is_zero():
            axis = Vec3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
            angle = 0
            return (axis, angle)

        axis = xyz.normalised()
        angle = math.acos(self.w) * 2.0
        return (axis, angle)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have an extra underscore in `___mul__`. Try `__mul__`.